# PHP: use return as key / value pair for a parent array

Tags: php, arrays

Well, after I rewrote my problem description 2 times i'll do it somehow less abstract now.

I need a way to return data within an array so that this array accepts this returned data as native key / value pair.

Illustration:

simple array:

```
$a = array('a' => 'b');
```

I could access the value of 'a' by simply calling $a['a']... clearly

I now need a way to exactly get this result via a function call or hack or something!

something like

```
$a = array(foo('a','b'));
```

the problem is, when "foo" return an array, the structure of my $a (array) will look like this:

```
array(array('a','b')) and not like array('a' => 'b')
```

and will prevent me from being able to access the data via $a['a']

The reason I need this is that I instance objects on demand within this array definition and also modify these instances on the fly, but I do need 2 different returns (of functions) of one and the same object and don't want to copy past half the initialization. Further more I don't want to first declare object instances outside the array because this would be a absolute overkill and would perfectly destroy all readability.

So.. is there a possibility to extract returned values to native language features?

PS. I also don't want to iterate over the array to re-process the data

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo($key) {
    $r = array(
       'a' => 'b',
        $key2 => $value2,
        $key3 => $value3,
        $key4 => $value4
        // ...
    );
    return $r[$key];
}

$a = foo('a'); // means $a = 'b';
```

Do it solves your problem ?

Comment: That won't solve my problem.
in this case I would need an ID and Object returned by "foo()" (ID as native KEY and Object as native VALUE)
I need this returned ID to later access the values of the array again.
So lets say the function would determine 1a6sh3hs3 as ID; so the array must look like this: array('1a6sh3hs3' => processedObject )

Comment: foo() returns object ??

Comment: *updated my first reply to your solution. The object *must not* be converted to an array. I need this objects. I seem not to be able to describe my problem exactly enough. The function must return a *native* pair to the array surrounding it

Comment: could you post any example of a simple output of `foo()` ? what are you saying in comment is different from your question

Comment: I don't know what would be the correct thing to return by the function. That's the point. The function would need to return *a native langue construct* or something so that the array surrounding the function gets filled with a *native key* and *native value* returned by the function. It does not even matter *what* concretely is returned. I just need the function to return a *native key* and *native value* for the array which is surrounding the function. Did I manage to make it a bit more clear?

Comment: excuse me, what does **native key** and **native value** means? I dont understand

Comment: Okay, I wrote a concrete example that shall be able to make clear what I mean: http://nopaste.info/80c92ac5e3.html ... I think its not possible to return this native key / value pair with a function like I would like to. That's why I am asking for an hack or something to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = foo('a','b');
```

with

```
function foo($x,$y) {
    return array($x => $y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `foo()` is returning an array, why not;

```
$a = foo('a','b');
```

Seems simple enough, *right?*

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way:**

```
$a[]= foo();

function foo() { 
    return array(1,2); 
}
```

**Or use reference:**

```
$value = NULL;
$a = array(foo($value), $value);
```

with

```
function foo(&$value) {
    $value = 'b';
    return 'a';
}
```